# How to kill (and close) tabs from pid?

Tags: c, winapi, browser, tabs, kill

How can I kill and close a tab of the browser from his pid?
I tried the command:

```
int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```

but it not works because Visual Studio says that the kill identifier is not found. I added all the libraries (sys/types.h, signal.h)

Then I tried the `TerminateProcess(HANDLE,UINT)` command. It works with programs (can close every window) but it not works with the browser tabs: it clears the content of the tab but the tab still remains opened.

How can I resolve?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you trying to close Chrome which creates multiple processes, you end up closing the wrong process. If you have a window `HWND` handle you should close the window instead.

Comment: I think you should search about a possible API in your browser that would allow clean method to do that. Please add with what browser you want do that. (only one because otherwise your question will be too broad)

Comment: Why do you expect killing a process to close a browser tab?

Comment: To automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot close a tab by killing the process. Modern browsers use child processes for their web content for security and stability reasons. If a child process dies the browser assumes that it crashed and will restore or ask the user if they want to restore the page.

The [ShellWindows object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773974(v=vs.85).aspx) allows you to interface with open Internet Explorer windows.